# How to solve undefined wp_insert_post error?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, insert

I am trying to post on WordPress but the wp_insert_post gives an error like this.

```
Undefined function 'wp_insert_post'.
```

I tried to solve this error by loading the wp-load.php file but I could not get any resolved. I searched for other ways to solve but there was only the wp-load.php way. So is there anyway else I can solve with?
Here is my code:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');
$script_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
$currentDay = date('D');   //$d = date(‘D’);
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('es_ES', IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 'Europe/Madrid', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);
$data1 = $formatter->format(time());

//to use built in wordpress function
require_once ('./wp-load.php');

//post variables
$postType = 'post';
$userID = 1;
$categoryID = '2';
$postStatus = 'publish';

$leadTitle = "Test post date:".$data1."";
$leadContent = '<h1>First Post</h1><p>This is my first post on wordpress.</p>';
$leadContent .= '<!--more--> <p>I am learning to post on wordpress.</p>';


$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $loadTitle,
    'post_content' => $leadContent,
    'post_status' => $postStatus,
    'post_author' => $userID,
    'post_type' => $postType,
    'post_category' => array($categoryID)
);

//Wordpress post function
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

$finaltext = '';

if($post_id){
    $finaltext = 'Yes, I made a new post.<br>';
}else{
    $finaltext .= 'Something went wrong.<br>';
}

echo $finaltext;
?>
```

Comment: _"I am trying to post on WordPress"_ - and _why_ are you trying to do that from "outside" WP, in a stand-alone file, to begin with?

Comment: It is required to do it from the outside.

Comment: Yes, you have to load wp-load.php so you can use Wordpress default functions

Comment: @RohitVyas I have loaded it but still get the error.

Comment: You could try using the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) instead (but that means you'll need to add some authentication stuff to your code as well).

Comment: "from the outside" does not have to mean stand-alone scripts. Set up a proper API endpoint for this.

Comment: I tried your code and it's working properly. I created one blank file in the root folder and put your code. I can add a post.

Comment: @RohitVyas where is your wp-load.php file located?

Comment: at the root level.

Comment: Can you write your require_once path please?

Comment: I created a check.php file at the root level and I used your code. require_once ('./wp-load.php');